# How to fold a cell of table in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In an `org-mode` table, I have a cell with a long line of text.  How do I fold that line/cell so that its column won't be too wide on the screen?

Comment: Manual: [column width and alignment](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html#Column-width-and-alignment).

Comment: I instead use 'meta-enter' to insert one or two empty row and puts the rest of the sentence in the cell below.

Comment: please provide a minimal working example of your table so that members can help you with your particular case.

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47236/8353) helps.